# Google Spreadsheets and MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to perform mass mailing via  Google Spreadsheets. The code itself works, however, when I try to call the UDF I coded in Google Spreadsheets, it responds that I have no permissions for the method despite the fact my Google account has required permissions for the script to run (thus allowing it to perform test runs from App Script).

> Exception: You do not have permission to call MailApp.sendEmail. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail (line 12).

Must I set Google Spreadsheets permissions somehow?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Это стаковерфлоу на русском. Вам бы лучше задать этот вопрос на англоязычной версии. И нужен ваш код, чтобы понять что именно у вас не работает.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253205/