# Google Spreadsheets и MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script

Мне необходимо осуществить массовую рассылку писем при помощи Google Spreadsheets. Код сам по себе работает, однако, при вызове функции в Google Spreadsheets отвечает, что не хватает разрешений, однако в моем Google-аккаунте разрешений достаточно (и в Apps Script код работает, рассылает письма, как и должен).

> Exception: You do not have permission to call MailApp.sendEmail. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail (line 12).

Необходимо ли мне каким-либо образом выставить разрешения для Google Spreadsheets?
Код прилагаю ниже

```
function MASSMAIL(cellEmail, cellTitle, cellText) 
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), ssname = ss.getSheetByName('Mailing');
    if(ssname == null) return "ERROR: must be used on 'mailing' page!"
    var title = ssname.getRange(cellTitle).getValue();
    var text = ssname.getRange(cellText).getValue();
    if(title == "" || text == "") return "ERROR: empty title or main body!";

    var email = ssname.getRange(cellEmail).getValue();
    var rng = ssname.getRange(cellEmail);
    while(email != "") {
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, title, text);
      rng = rng.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN);
      email = rng.getValue();
    }
    return "emails successfully sent";
}
```

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: А в каком контексте запускается эта функция? Я вижу, что она принимает параметры, значит запускается не самостоятельно. Может через простой триггер ?

Comment: Да, в качестве параметров она принимает три клетки: cellEmail - первая клетка в столбце с почтовыми адресами, cellTitle принимает клетку с титулом письма и, соответственно, cellText - с текстом письма.

Проблема не в том, что она запускается не самостоятельно, вызываю я ее верно, проблема именно в том, что рассылка не осуществляется за отсутствием разрешений для использования метода MailApp.sendEmail, причем дело не в разрешения именно моего аккаунта Google - у меня они есть.

Если я вместо рассылки буду логи писать в консоль, все пройдет, как надо, уже проверял.

Comment: Логи в консоль и MailApp требуют совершенно разных разрешений (точнее логи в консоль разрешений не требуют). Контекст запуска имеет ключевое значение. Учитывая то, что вы написали, я предполагаю, что данная функция запускается как формула в гугл таблице?

Comment: Или может из-под простого триггера?

Comment: Да, в гугл-таблице, Вы абсолютно правы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользовательские функции могут вызывать только определенные сервисы для выполнения сложных задач [Custom Functions > Advanced > Using Apps Script services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)

Отправки почты в этом списке нет.

> Если ваша функция выдает сообщение об ошибке "You do not have permission to call X service", значит служба требует авторизации пользователя и, следовательно, не может использоваться в пользовательской функции.
> Чтобы использовать службу, отличную от перечисленных [тут](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services), создайте настраиваемое меню, которое запускает вашу функцию. Скрипт, который запускается из меню, при необходимости запрашивает у пользователя авторизацию и, следовательно, может использовать все службы Apps Script.

Comment: Попробую и дам обратную связь, благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Вы не можете отправлять почту через пользовательские формулы.